# After 5.18.4 Upgrade, Cases are Missing from the List

Tags: civicase

After Drupal 7.67 and CiviCRM 5.18.4 upgrades, when you click on add a case, the correct screen opens, you can enter data, then save, and the number of cases showing in the constituent summary is incremented, but no new cases show up in a list to be managed. This was previously, for several years on prior versions, working correctly, Also, even for existing cases, the activity dropdown list is not being populated, although they have worked in the past and the Activity Type Options are correctly setup.

So now, in short, the number of cases in the Contact Summary is correct, such as 2 for a certain client, but when you click on the Cases tab, only 1 case appears. CiviCRM was no upgraded to 5.19.0 and the problem persists.

Examining the Case data directly in the database shows no clear reason for this. Furthermore the options for activity_type for the CiviCase component are also in the database and match those of a fresh install.

Has anyone run into this or can you suggest other things I can do to troubleshoot?

Comment: What was the previous version before upgrade?

Comment: It was 4.6.x leapfrogging to 5.10, then to 5.18.4

Comment: Ok check the case type definition then. It's possible something didn't get upgraded in there and that might explain the missing activity dropdown choices. Also check in sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog and there's a log file in there that might indicate some upgrade issues.

Comment: Thanks! I will check this out.

Comment: @hershel I see your edit - were you able to check the CASE TYPE definition (not the activity type option_values), i.e. `select * from civicrm_case_type`. And is it using external xml files or is the definition column in that table populated?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here was missing XML files. If you run an upgrade and accidentally override the CiviCase XML configuration files, then this will happen.

The solution is to put back those files and CiviCRM may pick them up and import them into the database. If not, you may need to manually copy and paste the XML definitions into the `civicrm_case_type` table.

Comment: Note you can store the files in your custom templates folder (as defined at admin - system settings - directories) so they don't get overwritten on upgrades. i.e. custom_templates/CRM/Case/xml/configuration.